# Export Images into PPT using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, powerpoint

I have to export some images into .ppt format using JavaScript. Actually I have to take snapshot of the web page on button click and convert it into PDF & PPT format. I have successfully converted images into PDF but I don't have any idea on how can I convert them into PPT. How can I achieve this? Any ideas welcome!

Comment: how did you do the pdf part? where is your code?